# A continuous map from a T2 & compact space to a uniform space is uniformly continuous.

Tags: topological-groups

Can you recommend some literature that give a proof of this statement, and who allegedly prove it first?

BTW, is there any use of uniform spaces or topological spaces in mathematical (or theoretical) physics?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can find this in Kelley's General topology.

Comment: It is in the general topology book of Bourbaki. If that is not the first published proof, it is probably in the paper of Andre Weil that introduced uniform space as entourages.